# jQuery selecting with regular-expression and replacing links

Tags: jquery, regex

I want to find all images inside some div and replace the image tag with some other code. Replace this:

`<div id='sd'>
<img src="/images/panorami/53.jpg">
<img src="/images/panorami/other.jpg">
</div>`

with:

`<div id='sd'>
<a title="" rel="lightbox[images]" href="/images/panorami/53x.jpg">
<img src="/images/panorami/53.jpg"></a>
<a title="" rel="lightbox[images]" href="/images/panorami/otherx.jpg"><img src="/images/panorami/other.jpg"></a>
</div>`

how this can be done with jQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('#sd img').wrap(function() {
    return $('<a />', {
        title: '',
        rel: 'lightbox[images]',
        href: this.src
    });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/ZFVwq/).

Comment: Nice - I really need to use that callback more often.

Comment: As @[Viacheslav Molokov](http://stackoverflow.com/users/226367/viacheslav-molokov) has [pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5498730/jquey-selecting-whit-regular-expression-and-replacing-links/5498901#5498901), this solution does not add `x` to the filename in the link. Replace `href: this.src` with e.g. `href: this.src.replace(/(\.[^.]+)$/i, 'x$1')` to get the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @jensgram answer, but with changed links like in question:

```
$(function() {
    $('#sd img').wrap(function() {
        fixed_url = $(this).attr('src').replace(/(\.[a-zA-Z]+)$/, 'x$1');
        return $('<a />', {
            title: '',
            rel: 'lightbox[images]',
            href: fixed_url
        });
    });
});
```

Example http://jsfiddle.net/sUsmA/1/

Comment: +1 Didn't notice that difference. `href` could have been set directly: `href: this.src.replace(/(\.[a-z]+)$/i, 'x$1')` but that's a matter of taste :)